# Spring WebMvcConfigurer running twice

Tags: spring

I've noticed a strange behaviour in my Spring web application:

My `WebMvcConfigurer` implementation is running twice and I don't know why. I'm very new using Spring.

Here are all my classes I think are part of the problem. All of them are inside the same package `br.com.cmabreu.config` (ask if you need more information). I'm using `5.0.4.RELEASE`:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

}


public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer 
    extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super( LoginSecurityConfig.class );
    }

}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "br.com.cmabreu.*")
public class LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private ComboPooledDataSource dataSource;   

    public void setDataSource(ComboPooledDataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }


}

public class AppInitializer 
    extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public ComboPooledDataSource getDataSource() {
        ComboPooledDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        ...
    }

}
```

The execution order is:

```
1) SecurityWebApplicationInitializer
2) AppInitializer
3) HibernateConfig
4) WebConfig
5) LoginSecurityConfig
6) WebConfig ( AGAIN )
```

If I remove `@ComponentScan` from `LoginSecurityConfig` then the init sequence throws an error just after `AppInitializer` because it can't find `HibernateConfig`:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4641)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:671)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: How can I know the execution order? Just `System.out.println("X");` at  all classes methods  when `X` is a number sequence.

Comment: Note: After move the `HibernateConfig` to other package and be more specific to this package in `@ComponentScan` all my controllers stop working but solved the main problem...I think there is something wrong in the Spring scanner here ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@EnableWebMvc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html) annotation itself imports the Spring MVC configuration from WebMvcConfigurationSupport (with default methods).

You do not need to apply it to the class implementing WebMvcConfigurer (with default methods).